# Special name for royal titles?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, names, hypernyms, nicknames

Is there a name for the title/nickname that some members of royalty get? For example, "King Larry the Kind".

Answer (score 7):

*Epithet* is the closest in one of its meanings precisely matching "the Kind" (or "the Conqueror", "the Bastard", "the Great" for well-known historical case). Unfortunately, a more recent sense focusing on derogatory terms is increasingly the better known, to the point where it might seem wrong to some readers or listeners who don't know the earlier use.

*Cognomen* though that's also used of general nicknames, and part of the historical Roman naming system (the term's origin).

*Sobriquet* if it **replaces** their name (so Caligua would be an example).

Edit: Some time later, but I've suddenly just remembered the word *byname*, while having more general senses, is uses for the sort of "X the Y" name that distinguished them from other monarchs, etc. of the same name.

Comment: And, arguably, 'He who must not be named'.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to looking for a *sobriquet*, an *epithet*, or a *moniker*.

Comment: *Moniker* for royalty?

Comment: @JonHanna Yeah well, I wasn’t sure he meant strictly royals.  Think of something like “Billy the Kid”; we aren’t talking about Prince William here, but he certainly has an epithet attached there. Plus he has nicknames in the tags, so I wasn’t quite sure how far and where he might be going.

Comment: It's pretty slangy. It can also mean given name, so for Billy the Kid it would cover, "Billy the Kid", "Billy", "William H. Bonney", "William Henry McCarty, Jr." and "Henry Antrim", as he used all those names. Still, *moniker* is a pretty interesting word, one of the few believed to be from Irish Traveller cant that has wide use in English.

Comment: _Monarcher_ for royalty?

Answer (score 0):

I can produce no evidence for its use, but calling it an *attributive* could, I think, be defeneded.

Answer (score 0):

"the Kind" the "Great" are epithets, that is correct. Just to add something to this discussion:

Style refers to the address a particular member of the aristocracy should be attributed to. For example, the Queen gets a style of "Her Majesty" and other members of the Royal Family gets "His/Her Royal Highness".

Also, there are several ways to style a prince or a princess.For example, the Prince of Wales is styled as 'HRH **The** Prince Charles, Prince of Wales'. On the other hand, the Princess Royal is styled as HRH **The** Princess Anne, Princess Royal. As a son of the English Monarch, a royal prince gets to have THE prefixed on his name. Compare this with HRH Prince William, Duke of Cambridge, and HRH Prince Henry of Wales. Obviously, as soon as their father, THE Prince Charles, assumes the throne, they will be styled, respectively as HRH THE Prince Charles, Duke of Cambridge, and HRH THE Prince Henry.